# Matlab: trying to estimate multifractal spectrum from time series by histogram box-counting

Tags: matlab, statistics, time-series, histogram, fractals

I am using the approach from this Yale page on fractals:
http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/MultiFractals/Moments/TSMoments/TSMoments.html
which is also expounded on this set of lecture slides (slide 32):
http://multiscale.emsl.pnl.gov/docs/multifractal.pdf

The idea is that you get a dataset, and examine it through many histograms with increasing numbers of bars i.e. resolution. Once resolution is high enough, some bars take the value zero. At each of these stages, we take the number of results that fall into each histogram bin (neglecting any zero-valued bins), divide it by the total size of the dataset, and raise this to a power, q. This operation gives the 'partition function' for a given moment and bin size. Quoting the above linked tutorial: "Provides a selective characterization of the nonhomogeneity of the
measure, positive q’s accentuating the densest regions and negative q’s the smoothest regions."

So I'm using the histogram function in Matlab, looping over bin sizes, summing over all the non-zero bin contents, and so forth. But my output array of partition functions is just a bunch of 1s. I can't see what's going wrong, can anybody else?

Data for intel, cisco, apple and others is available on the same Yale website: yale.edu/fractals/MultiFractals/Finf(a)/Finf(a).html

N.B. `intel` refers to the intel stock price I was originally using as the dataset.

```
lower = 1; %set lowest level of histogram resolution (bin size)
upper = 300; %set highest level of histogram resolution (bin size)

qlow = -20; %set lowest moment exponent
qhigh = 20; %set highet moment exponent
qstep = 0.25; %set step size between moment exponents

qn= ((qhigh-qlow)/qstep) + 1; %calculates number of steps given qlow, qhigh, qstep

qvalues= linspace(qlow, qhigh, qn); %creates a vector of q values given above parameters

m = min(intel); %find the maximum of the dataset
M = max(intel); %find the minimum of the dataset

for Q = 1:length(qvalues) %loop over moment exponents q 


    for k = lower:upper %loop over bin sizes

        counts = hist(intel, k); %unpack all k histogram height values into 'counts'
        counts(counts==0) = []; %delete all zero values in ''counts

        Zq = counts ./ length(intel);
        Zq = Zq .^ qvalues(Q);
        Zq = sum(Zq);

        partitions(k-(lower-1), Q) = Zq; %store Zq in the kth row and the Qth column of 'partitions'

    end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to understand what's going on? You can seet a breakpiont, for example on the first `counts = ... ` line and then hit the "step" button in the user interface repeatedly while watching how the variables change. I don't have the `intel` data available, and I don't know what the result should be, so at this point it's probably best to try yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be generally bug-free but I made some changes since you perform needless repetitions over loops (I moved the outer loop inside and "vectorized" it since all moment calculations can be performed simultaneously for a given histogram. Also, it is building the histogram that takes longest).

```
intel = cumsum(randn(64,1)); % <-- mock random walk
Ni =length(intel);

%figure, plot(intel)


lower = 1; %set lowest level of histogram resolution (bin size)
upper = 300; %set highest level of histogram resolution (bin size)

qlow = -20; %set lowest moment exponent
qhigh = 20; %set highet moment exponent
qstep = 0.25; %set step size between moment exponents

qn= ((qhigh-qlow)/qstep) + 1; %calculates number of steps given qlow, qhigh, qstep

qvalues= linspace(qlow, qhigh, qn); %creates a vector of q values given above parameters

m = min(intel); %find the maximum of the dataset
M = max(intel); %find the minimum of the dataset

partitions = zeros(upper-lower+1,length(qvalues));
for k = lower:upper %loop over bin sizes

    % (1) Select a bin size r and partition [m,M] into intervals of size r:
        % [m, m+r), [m+r, m+2r), ..., [m+kr, M], where m+kr < M <= m+(k+1)r.
    % Call these bins B0, ..., Bk.

    edges = linspace(m,M,k+1);
    edges(end)=Inf;

    % (2) For each j, 0 <= j <= k, count the number of xi that lie in bin Bj. Call this number nj. Ignore all nj that equal 0 after all the xi have been counted..

    counts = histc(intel, edges); %unpack all k histogram height values into 'counts'
    counts(counts==0) = []; %delete all zero values in ''counts

    % (3) Now compute the qth moment, Mrq = (n0/N)q + ... + (nk/N)q, where the sum is over all nonzero ni.

    % Zq = counts/Ni;

    partitions(k, :) = sum( (counts/Ni) .^ qvalues); %store Zq in the kth row and the Qth column of 'partitions'

end

figure, hold on
loglog(1./[1:k]', partitions(:,1),'g.-')
loglog(1./[1:k]', partitions(:,80),'b.-')
loglog(1./[1:k]', partitions(:,160),'r.-')

% (4) Perform linear regressions here to get alpha(r) ....
```

Comment: Keep in mind, I don't know what was the source of your original problem. Although the problem you are working on is interesting, your question as posed was somewhat inadequate. You should pose minimal working problems that recreate the problem and it was not possible from the information you provided. As such your question could be flagged for removal.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time!  1) I tried editing the post for greater clarity. 2) I get an error at line 40 of your code `partitions(k, :) ...` I think because of raising to the power of `qvalues`, which is a vector holding 161 different values for `q`. That's why I had the loop over `q`s, with the loop over bin size embedded in it. I'm very new to Matlab, so I don't know a lot of the techniques you used. What does `partitions = NaN(upper-lower+1,length(qvalues))` do?

Comment: (correction): `qvalues` should be a column vector and `counts` a row vector. Check the `size` of `qvalues` and `counts` prior to that line to make sure they are properly shaped. The `NaN(...)` step initializes the array, but I changed that to `zeros(...)` which makes more sense here.

Comment: The size of `counts`, the histogram readout, is determined by the number of histogram bars - the current level of detail - ranging from 1 to 300. And  `counts(counts==0) = []` deletes all zero values so in general the size of `counts` will be `<=` the current level of detail. But `qvalues` is determined at the beginning of the code as being 161 equally spaced numbers ranging from -20 to 20. So in general, there's no reason for them to be the same size. Thanks again!

Comment: You've been extremely helpful, but I went against your advice and put back my original loop over q. And I _think_ it's working!!! I added some code to perform many linear regressions and store the slopes, and a separate script to compute the f(alpha) function. And it's returning the kind of results I wanted to see - a parabola shaped curve with a peak between 1<alpha<2. Been slaving over this for days! Can't thank you enough for your help, deepest regards.

Comment: @bibblybobbly It doesn't matter that you delete some entries in counts because in the end the sum operation collapses the array `(counts/Ni).^qvalues` to a vector with the length of `qvalues`. That is why its important that qvalues be a row vector and counts a column vector.

Comment: Please try running the answer I posted *exactly* as I posted it. It should work! You can start from here as a template. As a bonus, it is a **lot** faster than the code you posted

Comment: Anyway, glad its working for you, just note if my answer resolved your problem to accept it by clicking on the checkmark, common courtesy at SO